# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Order->order, expression 'Status' failed to locate a name ('Status')

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, backend, fastapi

**Cannot save record to my db.**

**I created endpoint which makes user and saves him to db:**

```
@router.post("/user/register/", tags=['user'], status_code=201)
async def user_register_web(user: RegisterWebSchema, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if user.password != user.password_repeat:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Passwords dont match each other!")

    db_user = UserModel(name=user.name.title(), surname=user.surname.title(), email=user.email,
                        phone_number=user.phone_number, login=user.login, password=user.password,
                        photo=None, is_admin=False, coins=0)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return {"JWT Token": signJWT(user.email),
            **user.dict()}
```

**Here is model of my User:**

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    surname = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    phone_number = Column(String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
    login = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    photo = Column(String(80), nullable=True)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    coins = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address.id"), nullable=False)
    address = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")

    pin = relationship("Pin", back_populates="user")
    payment_card = relationship("PaymentCard", back_populates="user")
    order = relationship("Order", back_populates="user")
    feedback = relationship("Feedback", back_populates="user")
    post = relationship("Post", back_populates="user")
    comment = relationship("Comment", back_populates="user")
    animal = relationship("Animal", back_populates="user")
    walk = relationship("Walk", back_populates="user")
```

**and here is the error I get:**

**sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Order->order, expression 'Status' failed to locate a name ('Status'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'database.models.OrderModel.Order'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.**

**model of Order:**

```
class Order(Base):
__tablename__ = "order"
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    order_code = Column(String(15), nullable=True)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    
    status_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("status.id"), nullable=False)
    status = relationship("Status", back_populates="order")
    payment_method_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("payment_method.id"), nullable=False)
    payment_method = relationship("PaymentMethod", back_populates="order")
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="order")
    
    post_office = relationship("PostOffice", back_populates="order")
    product = relationship("Product", secondary=OrderProduct, back_populates="order")
```

**and model of Status:**

```
class Status(Base):
__tablename__ = "status"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    
    order = relationship("Order", back_populates="status")
```

I createrd migration successfully and then db. I dont understand why it shows lack of relationship, which i created. And it appears in lines of codes which dont even use these Tables.

Comment: Are `Order` and `Status` in the same module?  If not, try importing `Status` into the module that defines `Order`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work I had to import all of my modules into api file with endpoint. I don't know why but it works right now.